# How to add custom choose file in angular material forms for document upload

Tags: html, css, angular6, angular-material-6

I am working on the file upload/document upload for my app, wanting to customise the way the file upload looks this way using angular material, new to it, so wanting assistance on how to use the angular material to get this working.

New to Angular Material, need guidance on doing this.

[image: Choose Image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `label` as parent of input and hide the input and customise you label as you need, like this example:

```css
.upload-btn>input {
  display: none
}

.upload-btn {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.upload-btn:active {
  background: #ddd
}
```

```html
<label class="upload-btn">
 Upload or icon here
 <input type="file">
</label>
```